# Dovecot Error: Namespace 'Mail storage autodetection failed with home=/home/username

Tags: dovecot

Server is Centos 7 running Dovecot 2.2.36 and SendMail 8.14.7. Postfix 2.10.1 is installed but not running.

We've been running a SendMail / Dovecot combination for 20 years and across 3 server/OS migrations without anything other than minor issues but this last week, mail hasn't been delivered to users with internal email addresses via their mail client.

We send a lot of mail via SendMail to members with external email addresses and these work fine.

It is users with mail accounts on our server that can't download any mail whether it is internal or external.
The mail is visible using Webmin and it's stored in /var/spool/mail/*username* but when I check the mail-log there are entries like

> Error: Namespace '':Mail storage autodetection failed with home=/home/username.

None of the users have a MailDir in their /home location and as far as I can tell they haven't since we stopped using Postfix some time ago.

Most of the Dovecot conf files look fairly vanilla with almost no uncommented lines and I'm not even sure which ones to look at as I administer it through Webmin.

**dovecot.conf has**

```
protocols = pop3
!include conf.d/*.conf
```

**10mail-conf has**

```
#mail_location = 
inbox = yes
mail_privileged_group = mail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
```

**20-pop3.conf has:**

```
pop3_uidl_format = %v.%u
```

.. and that's about it as all the rest seem to be commented out.
If I need to provide more configuration information please let me know and thanks for any guidance.

Output from `dovecot -n`:

```
auth_verbose = yes
debug_log_path = syslog
disable_plaintext_auth = no
info_log_path = syslog
mail_privileged_group = mail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent  }
 mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent  }
 mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash  }
 prefix =}
passdb {
  driver = pam}
pop3_uidl_format = %v.%u
protocols = pop3
ssl = no
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd}
```

Update: I tried creating both 'mail' folders and Mailbox folders in the user /home directory and then trying to force a sync using doveadm and that gets rid of the error message about the mail storage auto-detection but doesn't retrieve any mail.

> mail dovecot: pop3(username): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/0, size=0

From what I've read, I'm assuming that there should be a mail/.pop3/INBOX folder in the user /home location but it doesn't seem to work if I create them manually so there must be some mechanism to create them that I can't find or a way to force Dovecot to sync the mail file with those /home folders.